# az acr build requored <SOURCE_LOCATION> parameter

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I'm following the directions on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/3-exercise-build-images?pivots=csharp)

While executing a command:

```
az acr build --registry <container_registry_name> --image webimage
```

I'm receiving

> the following arguments are required: <SOURCE_LOCATION>

But per the documentation, <SOURCE_LOCATION> is not a required parameter.

Has anyone encountered such a case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went to the root folder of the application and added a point at the end of the command. In such a way I passed the location where the code exists (<SOURCE_LOCATION>).

```
az acr build --registry <container_registry_name> --image webimage .
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems this [**`issue`**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53257) had been already reported , however you could resolve this by passing the location where the code exists